# Does $k(s_1,s_2)=k(x,y^2)$ imply that $k[s_1,s_2]=k[x,y^2]$, where $s_1,s_2$ are symmetric w.r.t. $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, involutions

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Let $\beta: k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$ be the involution (a $k$-algebra automorphism of order two) defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.

The set of symmetric elements with respect to $\beta$,
denote it by $S_\beta$, is of the form
$a_{2n+2}y^{2n+2}+a_{2n}y^{2n}+\cdots+a_2y^2+a_0$,
where $a_{2n+2},a_{2n},\ldots,a_2,a_0 \in k[x]$.

The set of skew-symmetric elements with respect to $\beta$,
denote it by $K_\beta$, is of the form
$a_{2n+1}y^{2n+1}+a_{2n-1}y^{2n-1}+\cdots+a_3y^3+a_1y$,
where $a_{2n+1},a_{2n-1},\ldots,a_3,a_1 \in k[x]$.

Clearly, $S_\beta=k[x,y^2]$.
($K_\beta$ is not a subalgebra of $k[x,y]$, since, for example, 
the product of two skew-symmetric elements is a symmetric element).

> Assume that $s_1,s_2 \in S_{\beta}$ are such that $k(s_1,s_2)=k(x,y^2)$.

In this situation:

> **Question 1:** Is it possible to find the 'exact' form of such $s_1,s_2$?

(An attempt to answer Question 1: We can write $x=G(s_1,s_2)$ and $y=H(s_1,s_2)$, for some
$G,H \in k(U,V)$.
Then perhaps (if not dividing by zero) we can substitute $(x,y)$ by $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$. Also, we can differentiate by $x$ and by $y$).

Example: $s_1=y^2+x^2+x$ and $s_2=y^2+x^2$; in this case actually, $k[s_1,s_2]=k[x,y^2]$.

This example leads to the following question:

> **Question 2:** Is it true that $k(s_1,s_2)=k(x,y^2)$ implies that
>   $k[s_1,s_1]=k[x,y^2]$?

Notice that taking $s_1=x^2,s_2=x^3$ is not a counterexample to Question 2, because $k(s_1,s_2)=k(x^2,x^3)=k(x) \subsetneq k(x,y^2)$.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: $(s_1,s_2)=(x,xy^2)$

Comment: @reuns, nice counterexample to Question 2, thanks! What about Question 1? Any ideas? Is there an additional 'mild' condition that guarantees a positive answer to Question 2?

Comment: @reuns, concerning an additional 'mild' condition that guarantees a positive answer to Question 2: What about $s_1(x,0) \neq 0, s_2(x,0) \neq 0$?

Comment: Your condition is of course not sufficient, $GL_2(k)$ is a subgroup of $Aut(k[u,v])$.  You want to know all the subrings $k[f,g]$ of $k[u,v]$ that keep the same fraction field ? 

The automorphism group of $k(u,v)$ is generated by a few elementary transformations (try finding them all), I don't know if the same holds for the endomorphisms of $k[u,v]$ of finite index.

Comment: @reuns, thank you for your comment; interesting. Please, could you find a counterexample to Question 2+ $s_1(x,0) \neq 0, s_2(x,0) \neq 0$?

Comment: $GL_2(k) \to Aut(k[s_1,s_2])$...

Comment: @reuns, please could you explain your last comment? I am not sure I understand it..

Comment: $(s_1,s_2) \mapsto (as_1+bs_2,cs_1+ds_2)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. We can take $(s_1,s_2)=(x,xy^2+x)$.

Comment: @reuns, but what if we avoid such cases? For example, if we further assume that $k[s_1(x,0),s_2(x,0)] \subsetneq k[x]$?

Comment: @reuns, also, is the following claim true? Claim: If $k(s_1,s_2)=k(x,y^2)$, then there exists an automorphism $g$ of $k[s_1,s_2]$ such that $k[g(s_1),g(s_2)]=k[x,y^2]$. It seems that $(s_1,s_2)=(x,xy^2)$ is again a counterexample, but how can we prove this?

Comment: It is the opposite : $f,g\in k[u,v]$ and $k(f,g)=k(u,v)$ iff $(u,v) \mapsto (f,g)$ is an automorphism of $k(u,v)$ which restricts to an endomorphism of $k[u,v]$, equivalently $\phi : (u,v) \mapsto (f,g)$ is an  endomorphism of $k[u,v]$ and $k[u,v]/\phi(k[u,v])$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @reuns, thank you very much! Sounds very interesting iff claim! (altough I do not know how to prove it, or how to apply it in my question, except $f=s_1, g=s_2, u=x, v=y^2$, I guess).